# Does Flutter 2.2. Desktop beta support Firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

From Stackoverflow previous questions it looks previous versions of Flutter prior to 2.2 did not support Firestore for desktop app. Does it support with version 2.2?

Comment: Who needs to support a platform is the package (if flutter already suports that platform), currently the cloud_firestore plugin only suports: android, ios, macos and web, see on its page: https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

Comment: @JorgeVieira, noted, kindly put this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who needs to support a platform is the package (if flutter already suports that platform), currently the cloud_firestore plugin only suports: android, ios, macos and web, see on its page: [cloud_firestore](http://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore)